# Is it possible to beat the main story of GTA V using only non-lethal weapons and tactics?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is it possible to beat the main story of GTA V with never having the character you are currently playing as kill someone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Sorry about that.

There are missions in the main story where there is no alternative to killing people. Listing them all would be futile, but an example as Michael in the [By the Book](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/By_the_Book) mission.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's not possible. Some missions that include the death of a person is:

- Prologue - killing security guard
- Carbine Rifles
- Hotel Assassination
- Fresh Meat
- Lamar Down

These are just to name a few. Everything mission at least has to have someone killed. In others there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Streamer DarkViper has attempted this using a vast amount of knowledge from speedrunning the game. His strategies include letting unused characters get kills, getting police to kill people and insane cheesy strategies that in one case took 33 hours to beat one mission.

He does not use the stun gun as, despite its name, it kills people. Even if it didn't, it's not available until after some of the mandatory kills (the prologue guard for example).

As of Meltdown, his killcount is 98 (59 melee, 28 gunshot, 1 samsung).

Comment: [Samsung?](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/IFruit)

Comment: An exploding phone (from the meme about Samsung S7 batteries).